# Very similar components and templates. How re-use them?

Tags: angular

I have 2 (maybe more in the future) similar views in the application. Saying similar I mean these views are tables that differ by only one column. This column shows some configuration parameters. In the future it's possible there is more parameters (and more views). User switches between these views using tab component.

They have also similar logic: check permission, save changes, reset to default, get changes history etc.

I would like to avoid copy pasting code, so I think about the best solution:

1. One component and one template. In the template I will have some ng-if deciding which column show. But in this solution instead of copy pasting I will have "ng-if" hell.
2. One component and multiple templates. I've read that it's possible but it's not recommended.
3. One base abstract component and multiple deriving components (and multiple templates). This solution avoids copy pasting code in the components, but I still have to copy paste template code.
4. ? (Is there any other solution?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a base component with your template, all the common logic  and input parameters to customize that view.

Then you can add a component which has tabs and call the above component with input parameters

Comment: And how I can "customize that view"? Using some ng-if or ng switch?

Comment: if it is a table with different columns that you can have column names and data as input and use ngFor in template

Answer (score 1):

You should look into ngFor. It lets you create repeatable template. E.g you can input an array of parameters over an @Input-Binding into the Component. Then iterate over the array with ngFor.